# Sql Server Order by nvarchar field using substring in select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to use Order by clause in select statement to Order the nvarchar field in the following data.

```
1/2013
1/2014
2/2013
3/2013
5/2010
25/2013
115/2013
26/2014
```

I want to Order by result like the following:

```
5/2010
1/2013
2/2013
3/2013
25/2013
115/2013
1/2014
26/2014
```

I am using the following query but it wont work.

```
SELECT DebitNote
FROM DebitNote
ORDER BY CONVERT(
     INT, 
     SUBSTRING(debitnote, CHARINDEX('/', debitnote) + 1, 4), 
     CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(debitNOte, 0, CHARINDEX('/', debitNOte)))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @DebitNote TABLE (DebitNote VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @DebitNote (DebitNote)
VALUES 
('1/2013'), ('1/2014'), ('2/2013'),
('3/2013'), ('5/2010'),
('25/2013'), ('26/2014')

SELECT DebitNote 
FROM @DebitNote
ORDER BY CAST('1/' + DebitNote AS DATETIME)
```

Output -

```
DebitNote
-----------------
5/2010
1/2013
2/2013
3/2013
25/2013
1/2014
26/2014
```

**Update:**

```
DECLARE @DebitNote TABLE (DebitNote VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @DebitNote (DebitNote)
VALUES 
     ('1/2013'), ('1/2014'),
     ('2/2013'), ('3/2013'),
     ('5/2010'), ('25/2013'),
     ('26/2014'), ('116/2013'),
     ('115/2013'), ('315/2014')

SELECT DebitNote
FROM @DebitNote
ORDER BY 
       SUBSTRING(DebitNote, CHARINDEX('/', DebitNote) + 1, 4)
     , CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(DebitNote, 0, CHARINDEX('/', DebitNote)))
```

Comment: I have also values like 115/2013, 116/2013, 315/2014 etc.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb I write code in a way that I will understand with little effort in 12 months time. Equally this means that I would expect other developers to understand the thing with ease too.

So in this scenario I wouldn't hide this cryptic logic in the `ORDER BY` clause. I would make things more transparent by having the values as part of the `SELECT` clause.

```
DECLARE @t table (
   DebitNote nvarchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO @t (DebitNote)
  VALUES ('1/2013')
       , ('1/2014')
       , ('2/2013')
       , ('3/2013')
       , ('5/2010')
       , ('25/2013')
       , ('115/2013')
       , ('26/2014');

SELECT DebitNote
FROM   (
        SELECT DebitNote
             , CharIndex('/', DebitNote) As position_of_slash
             , Cast(SubString(DebitNote, 0, CharIndex('/', DebitNote)) As int) As first_part
             , SubString(DebitNote, CharIndex('/', DebitNote) + 1, 10) As last_part -- Note that the last parameter of the SubString() function here
                                                                                    -- equals the length of the field in question
        FROM   @t
       ) As x
ORDER
    BY last_part
     , first_part;
```

The last query could be made in to a CTE if preferred

```
; WITH component_parts AS (
  SELECT DebitNote
       , CharIndex('/', DebitNote) As position_of_slash
       , Cast(SubString(DebitNote, 0, CharIndex('/', DebitNote)) As int) As first_part
       , SubString(DebitNote, CharIndex('/', DebitNote) + 1, 10) As last_part -- Note that the last parameter of the SubString() function here
                                                                              -- equals the length of the field in question
  FROM   @t
)
SELECT DebitNote
FROM   component_parts
ORDER
    BY last_part
     , first_part;
```

Comment: gvee your answer is not working, it is not giving the desired result as the above output list, Any how good working explanation.

Comment: Try the updated code (missed off casting the `first_part` as `int`)